Security issues in Kurento Docker image
We are using Openvidu 2.29 for our video solution. When we run scan on Kurento docker image 7.0.1 we found some vulnerabilities. For the scan we are using AWS Elastic Container Registry Scan.
What can be done to resolve the issues?
Some references:
CVE-2020-36130  6.5 aom:1.0.0.errata1-3build1   MEDIUM  Open
CVE-2021-30473  9.8 aom:1.0.0.errata1-3build1   MEDIUM  Open
CVE-2020-36135  6.5 aom:1.0.0.errata1-3build1   MEDIUM  Open
CVE-2020-36129  8.8 aom:1.0.0.errata1-3build1   MEDIUM  Open
CVE-2021-30475  9.8 aom:1.0.0.errata1-3build1   MEDIUM  Open

